# Convert a class into JSON or List

Tags: dart, flutter

How to convert this class into JSON or List?

```
class cliente {
  int id;
  String nome;
  String apelido;
  String sexo;
  String status;
}
```

**Edit**

I'm changed my class and works fine to my case:

```
class client {
  Map<String, dynamic> fields => {
  "id": "",
  "name": "",
  "nickname": "",
  "sex": "",
  "status": "",
}
```

Then I use:

```
client.fields["id"]   = 1;
client.fields["name"] = "matheus";

sqlite.rowInsert("insert into client(id, name)", client.fields.Keys.toList(), client.fields.Values.toList());
```

Comment: Technically, JSON is a text format, but I'm guessing you want a map representation of the class?

Comment: @Irn what I want is to feed the class to then perform a `sqlite.rawInsert("insert..." fields, values)`. Then I'm using the @diegodeveloper tip, I changed my class, look my question again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a method inside your class and return a `Map<String, dynamic>`

```
  class cliente {
    int id;
    String nome;
    String apelido;
    String sexo;
    String status;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
          'id': id,
          'nome': nome,
          'apelido': apelido,
          'sexo': sexo,
          'status': status,
        };
  }
```

And use it for example :

```
final dataObject = new client(); 
...fill your object
final jsonData = dataObject.toJson();
```

Also you can try using this package to avoid writing all of your fields : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable